# How to play 2 Audiofiles in one response

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to have a personal greeting (mp3) in my Alexa Skill Launch Intent and start and audio stream directly when the first mp3 is finished. I tried it with responsebuilder and addaudioplayerplaydirective. But you can add only directive to a response, but I have 2 files to play after another. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

AudioPlayer is more ideal for long-form audio like meditations or songs. Once your skill starts the audio player, the custom skill sessions ends and your users can't do what they could normally do while in your skill.

It sounds more like you just want to play some shorter audio clips to greet your users. If that's the case and your audio files meet [the requirements](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apla-audio.html#audio-file-support), [APL for Audio](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-for-audio-reference.html), may be a better solution for you.

Here's an example directive your skill can include in its response to play two audio files, one after another, then have Alexa say something.

```
    {
  "type": "Alexa.Presentation.APLA.RenderDocument",
  "token": "developer-provided-string",
  "document": {
    "type": "APLA",
    "version": "0.91",
    "mainTemplate": {
      "parameters": [
        "payload"
      ],
      "item": {
        "type": "Sequencer",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "Audio",
            "source": "soundbank://soundlibrary/ui/gameshow/amzn_ui_sfx_gameshow_intro_01",
            "filters": [
              {
                "type": "Volume",
                "amount": "20%"
              },
              {
                "type": "FadeIn",
                "duration": 1000
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "Audio",
            "source": "soundbank://soundlibrary/alarms/beeps_and_bloops/bell_01"
          },
          {
            "type": "Speech",
            "content": "Hello world!"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If what you really need is the AudioPlayer, have your skill issue a directive to start the first clip. Then add a handler to your skill to capture the [PlaybackNearlyFinishedRequest](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#playbacknearlyfinished) event. In that, your handler should return another directive to queue up the next audio clip.